# Routing to specific HTTP method resource by specifying the method in URL

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to make it possible to use full functionality of my Jersey webservice by both using regular HTTP method calls (GET,PUT,POST,DELETE), and specifying the method in URL while using POST method.

So to delete `/resource` client will be able to use:

`DELETE /resource`

or

`POST /resource?method=DELETE`

Does jersey support that? Or what would be the least-intrusive way to implement that?

The only way I can think of would be writing a Filter which wraps the original HttpServletRequest with my class whose `getMethod` returns the parsed HTTP method from the URL. Is this the only solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What benefits does this give you over implementing the correct http verbs for your resource?

Comment: @bennettweb I need to make my service accessible by a variety of clients, there are some in the list that cant use DELETE or PUT methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add PostReplaceFilter to your app: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/PostReplaceFilter.html